# Calendar Library C++

Tags: c++, date, calendar

I have recently used the Calendar functions in QUANTLIB C++ to perform the below.

Unfortunately any project using QUANTLIB takes too long to compile.  I'm interested in interpreting strings of dates in multiple different formats (which quantlib enables me to do), as I have shown below.  I also want to find the difference between various dates in different formats etc.

My question is, is there another C++ library out there which enables me to do all of these things (hopefully one which will compile in my projects faster)?

The below simple project seems to take forever to compile.

My only prerequisite is that it compiles statically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <ql/utilities/dataparsers.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace QuantLib;

int main()
{

    Calendar cal = Australia();
    const Date dt(21, Aug, 1971);

    bool itis = false;

    itis = cal.isBusinessDay(dt);
    cout << "business day yes? " << itis << endl;
    cout << "The calendar country is: " << cal.name() << endl;


    // now convert a string to a date.
    string mydate = "05/08/2016";
    const Date d = DateParser::parseFormatted(mydate,"%d/%m/%Y");


    cout << "The year of this date is: " <<  d.year() << endl;
    cout << "The month of this date is: " <<  d.month() << endl;
    cout << "The day of this date is: " <<  d.dayOfMonth() << endl;
    cout << "The date " << mydate << " is a business day yes? " << cal.isBusinessDay(d) << endl;


}
```

Comment: You can try this: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html Not sure if it has all you need though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) is fully documented, open-source, and the part you require is header-only and compiles very fast.  It requires C++11 or better as it builds on `<chrono>`.

Your example looks like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace date;

int main()
{
    const auto dt = 21_d/aug/1971;
    auto wd = weekday{dt};

    auto itis = wd != sun && wd != sat;
    cout << "business day yes? " << itis << endl;

    // now convert a string to a date.
    istringstream mydate{"05/08/2016"};
    local_days ld;
    mydate >> parse("%d/%m/%Y", ld);
    auto d = year_month_day{ld};
    wd = weekday{ld};

    cout << "The year of this date is: " <<  d.year() << '\n';
    cout << "The month of this date is: " <<  d.month() << '\n';
    cout << "The day of this date is: " <<  d.day() << '\n';
    cout << "The date " << d << " is a business day yes? " << (wd != sun && wd != sat) << '\n';
}
```

The above program outputs:

```
business day yes? 0
The year of this date is: 2016
The month of this date is: Aug
The day of this date is: 05
The date 2016-08-05 is a business day yes? 1
```

The only sketchy part is lack of `isBusinessDay`.  But it is very easy to find day-of-the-week in this library (as demonstrated above).  And you could easily use this library to build a more complete `isBusinessDay` if you have a list of holidays for Australia.  For example:

```
bool
isBusinessDay(year_month_day ymd)
{
    sys_days sd = ymd;
    weekday wd = sd;
    if (wd == sat || wd == sun)  // weekend
        return false;
    if (sd == mon[2]/jun/ymd.year())  // Queen's Birthday
        return false;
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That's very useful.

Comment: I just though I would add to this.  I found a way to use some of the Quantlib libraries necessary for date functions.  Just include ql/time/calendar.hpp and ql/time/all.hpp  .  It works a treat.